# SSH challenge response if no keys

Tags: ssh

I am reviewing the security of one of our servers and wanted to see if SSH can ask for public keys when authenicating or use password &  challenge response if no key exists.

I cannot seem to work out how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way it already works.  Check the manpage.  Note that `public key authentication` comes before `challenge-response authentication`.

From the `AUTHENTICATION` section from the manage:

```
 The methods available for authentication are: GSSAPI-based authentication, host-based authentication, public key authentication,
 challenge-response authentication, and password authentication.  Authentication methods are tried in the order specified above,
 though protocol 2 has a configuration option to change the default order: PreferredAuthentications.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh in verbose mode

```
ssh -v user@server
```

You should see a line like this:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

You can disable certain authentications methods on server and client side. An you can change the order.